How to create a Constraint that has multiple labels in Memgraph?
I'm trying to create a constraint that encompasses multiple labels, which seems to be unsupported, or I'm missing the correct approach.
For context, creating a constraint with a single label works perfectly fine, like so:
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Employee) ASSERT EXISTS (n.first_name);
However, my requirement involves multiple labels for a node, and my attempt to create a similar constraint fails:
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Employee:Teacher) ASSERT EXISTS (n.first_name);
This attempt results in an error indicating a syntax issue:
Query failed: line 1:33 no viable alternative at input '(n:Employee:'
Is there a syntax or method in Memgraph that allows for creating constraints across multiple labels?

You can create a constraint on the Employee and on a Teacher node, if it is Teacher it will have a constraint, if it is Employee it will have constraint, but you have to do it with the following two lines:
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Employee) ASSERT EXISTS (n.first_name);
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Teacher) ASSERT EXISTS (n.first_name);

